# How do you divide a rounded rectangle using pathfinder using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I'd like to create a rounded rectangle that's cut evenly in half with the flat edge in the middle left open (#4). Once I created my rectangle using the rounded rectangle tool I created a line using the line segment tool in order to divide it in half (#1). Then I'll select both the line segment and the rounded rectangle and use the pathfinder divide tool. This causes the space in between to be filled with a black line (#2). Once the two halves are ungrouped the solid black line stays as part of the individual shapes (#3).
[image]

Comment: Pathfinder cant do this since it makes a assumption that everything in the world is a closed shape. Use dcissirs divide below or delete the edges you dont need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a rounded rectangle you will have a path that looks like this:
[image]

Go to Path> Add Anchor Points which adds anchor points exactly between the existing anchor points:
[image]

Then choose the scissors tool (keyboard shortcut is c) and click on the middle top point and the middle bottom point. This will "cut" the path at those 2 points.

Then simply move the paths apart and you will have what you show in your image # 4.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work exactly as expected for me in CS6.

[image]

Maybe Adobe broke it in newer releases.

Simply use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select and delete the new verticals.

Comment: This still works in CC, but the pieces are put inside a group for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @BillyKerr Pathfinder has had a tendency to Group the results for several versions. Even CS6 will create  group after using Divide. It's almost a "tick" for me to Pathfinder > Ungroup.

Comment: I have to say that the answer from @Scott more accurately answers the question, which is how to do this with Pathfinder. My answer is an alternate approach to the task desired.

Comment: The only problem I have with your answer @Kyle are the extra anchors added on the curves.. which AI can't effectively remove without altering the curves (But VectorScribe can).

Comment: Very much agreed about the extra anchors- Gotta love the Astute Graphics plug-ins...